# Why was surrogate class needed in JavaScript ES5 prototypal inheritance?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, prototypal-inheritance

I have a pretty good understanding of JavaScript's prototypal inheritance but I wouldn't say it's perfect. I am looking at the latest prototypal syntax for JavaScript inheritance and so far it makes pretty good sense.

`__proto__` is used for looking up parent function's `prototype`. Say I have `Cat` and `Mammal`, I can simply point `Cat.prototype.__proto__` to `Mammal.prototype`.

```
ChildClass.prototype.__proto__ = ParentClass.prototype;
ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;
```

The use of `__proto__` was strongly discouraged because it was not standardized only until recently. Thus, the modern standardized practice is to use `Object.create`

```
ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);
ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;
```

Now let's look at ES5's surrogate approach

```
function Surrogate() {};
Surrogate.prototype = ParentClass.prototype;
ChildClass.prototype = new Surrogate();
ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;
```

Obviously,

```
ChildClass.prototype = ParentClass.prototype;
```

is bad, because modifying ChildClass's prototype will also modify ParentClass's prototype.

But why can't we do this?

```
ChildClass.prototype = new ParentClass();
```

Why do we need a surrogate in between?

Comment: Personally I'd say your `ES5's surrogate approach` isn't entirely accurate. `Object.create` was added in `5.1` in 2011 so it's been around an extremely long time as far as modern JS goes.

Comment: `new` was used *before* ES5 introduced `Object.create`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why can't we do this?
>
> `ChildClass.prototype = new ParentClass();`

How do you know that calling `ParentClass` constructor w/o arguments would not throw an error?

Imagine `ParentClass` was implemented this way.

```
function ParentClass(name) {
  if(!name) throw new Error('name is required');

  this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you, good point! Is that the only reason for doing surrogate class? Is there any other hidden caveat I should be aware of and that surrogate trick is designed to catch?

Comment: @cfeng Any other side effect `ParentClass` could do. For example it might call external API, increment counter etc.

Comment: @cfeng We just don't want to call the constructor at all. What should it initialise? There's no instance around.